# How can I do to get the format dd/MM/yyyy using react.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to have the good format for the date : dd/MM/yyyy. Now I get 1606348737089 instead of the format dd/MM/yyyy. Here is my code :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'; 
  function App() {
    const [date, setdate] = useState(Date.now())
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{date}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }

export default App;
```

Here is my code : https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-engelbart-tzbxv?file=/src/App.js

Do you know how can I do this ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Date.now() returns a [millisecond timestamp since the epoch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now).

Comment: If you don't mind inlcuding another library, you could just use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) and do whatever format you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an function like below and pass the state value as parameter and just call the function in your render method ;)

```js
function formattedDate(stateValue = new Date) {
  let month = String(stateValue.getMonth() + 1);
  let day = String(stateValue.getDate());
  const year = String(stateValue.getFullYear());

  if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
  if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

  return `${day}/${month}/${year}`;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lightweight date library like dayjs to format your date:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import dayjs from 'dayjs';

  function App() {
    const [date, setdate] = useState(Date.now())
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{dayjs(date).format('DD/MM/YYYY')}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }

export default App;
```